# Printing a NxNxN Matrix

Tags: c#, oop, matrix

I have a NxNxN matrix generation code as follows:

```
namespace Physics
{
    class _3DMatrix
    {
         public int[, ,] m;

         public _3DMatrix(int size1, int size2, int size3, int a)
         {
             m = new int[size1, size2, size3];

             for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
             {
                 for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                 {
                     for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                     {
                         m[x, y, z] = a;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

        public void Print()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < m.Rank; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < m.Rank; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < m.Rank; z++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0} ", m[x, y, z]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented a print function which **fails to print the correct matrix**. 
How am I supposed to write a proper print function for a matrix of any dimension?

This is how I am calling the matrix:

_

```
3DMatrix m = new _3DMatrix(5, 4, 3, 0);
m.Print();
```

I should get all zeroes in 3 s1xs2 matrices, however I get
Here's a sample output:

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

0 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 0

I do understand the problem is due to the fact that I am using the rank property, but how to implement it correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: Define "fails completely". That doesn't tell us much of anything about what's going wrong. Compile error? What is it? Where? Did you google the error to figure out what it is and why it's happening? Have you tried to fix it? Same follows if it's a runtime exception. Maybe it's unexpected behavior -- what happened? What did you expect to happen? Please elaborate.

Comment: "fails completely"??? Does it fail to compile OR fail at runtime OR dos not do what you want?

Comment: edited question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, still need to answer more questions and dig deeper. Put some effort into the question so we can answer.  What happened? Be **specific**, showing output. What did you **expect** to happen? It's best to show a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Actually, I doubt this even compiles. In your constructor you refer to `size` but it's never declared anywhere and isn't a parameter to the constructor either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Rank` use `GetLength`.

According to [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.getlength)

> Gets a 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements in the specified dimension of the Array.

```
for (int x = 0; x < m.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < m.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
         for (int z = 0; z < m.GetLength(2); z++)
         {
              Console.Write("{0} ", m[x, y, z]);
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
 }
```